# Gradle Project Refresh Failed , Plugin with id 'android-sdk-manger' not found

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I am trying to Include a Android Library in Android Studio by Building locally in Android Studio with Gradle as described here
https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md
but as soon as I save and sync my `buld.gradle` I am given Error that `Gradle Project Refresh Failed , Plugin with id 'android-sdk-manger' not found`
further more I see in my main `build.gradle` that a plugin is included like
`classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.10.+'` , how do I fix it ?

Comment: Do you have `buildscript { repositories { mavenCentral() } }` in your build script? Does the error message say `android-sdk-manger` or `android-sdk-manager`?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser it is `android-sdk-manager` , it's depending on http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton.sdkmanager how to fix this?

Comment: Can you answer the other question as well?

Comment: yes that line is present

Comment: That's strange. Make sure that the `buildscript` repository and dependency declarations are present in the same build script that applies the `android-sdk-manager` plugin, and double-check the dependency coordinates. Perhaps also try to build from the command line. If you are behind a web proxy, you'll have to tell Gradle about it (see [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html)).

Comment: You can check the top level `build.gradle` inside this library. It uses  `classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.10.+'`.
You can/should add this file to your project, or you can copy the `buildscript` block inside your `build.gradle` (you need to copy also same variables)